# Maximum density knapsack with initial volume and constraint on number of items

Tags: dynamic-programming, knapsack-problems

Given $\{\rho_i,v_i\}_{i=1}^N$, the densities and volumes of $N$ items, and $K\in \mathbb{Z}_+$. Let $v_0=1$ be the initial volume, and the initial mass is zero. The values $\rho_i,v_i\in \mathbb{R}_+$. For $S\subseteq [N]$, the corresponding average density is
$$d(S):=\frac{\sum_{i\in S} \rho_i v_i}{v_0+\sum_{j\in S}v_j}, $$
and the resulting maximum density knapsack problem is
$$\max_{S\subseteq [N]} d(S), \quad
\text{with constraint}\ |S|\le K.$$

Given an additional parameter $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$, please design an algorithm that returns $S\subseteq [N]$ with $|S|\le K$ and
$$d(S)\ge (1-\varepsilon)d(S^*),$$
where $d(S^*)$ is the maximum density achievable. The algorithm should have running time $\mathrm{poly}\left(N,K,\log(\varepsilon^{-1}),\log(\rho_{\max}/\rho_{\min}),\log(v_{\max}/v_{\min})\right)$.

Comment: You might want to look into cardinality constrained knapsack algorithms first: [ref 1](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-24777-7) [ref 2](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X22000750)

Comment: OK, I see that the problem here is a variation of the problem (13.18) in the book Knapsack Problems, with $c_i\in \mathbb{R}_+,w_i=1$.